# Store and retrieve protocol buffer data from Memcached in Java

Tags: java, memcached, protocol-buffers, spymemcached, amazon-elasticache

I am using Protocol Buffers for my data and want to store and retrieve this data from Memcached (running on ElastiCache). I am using the MemcachedClient in Java.

I am currently storing data to Memcache using code similiar to this:

```
memClient.set("keyString", protobufBuilder.build().toByteArray());
```

But, I am not sure how to `get` this  data from Memcached and convert it back into a Protobuf object.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I simply typecasted the data I get from MemcachedCleint to `byte[]` and gave it as input to the `pasreFrom` method of my Protobuf object.